# Peer-to-Peer connection over the internet

Tags: java, networking

Is there any way to make a peer-to-peer connection over the internet without a server?
The idea is to send files from one PC to another PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do P2P networking over the Internet, you have to deal with several issues. Mainly, NAT Traversal and Firewalls. If you do not deal with these problems, your connections will be error-prone. It is best to use an existing P2P framework for this purpose. In Java, one of the major frameworks is JXSE which is an open-source implementation of the JXTA protocols. The project is now discontinued but there is plenty of documentation available. See, https://jxse.kenai.com.

If JXSE is too heavyweight/complex for your purposes, which it can be, I would use a smaller/simpler P2P library that implements some basic form of NAT Traversal or firewall hole-punching. This may not account for every case, but it may be able to work for the particular case at hand. There are a few of these open-source implementations available; Google it or look on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Write an application (server) that opens a socket to listen on some arbitrary port. Write another application (client) that sends a request to the IP address and port of the host running the server.

Comment: But this only works in a local network and not over the internet

Comment: That depends on the networks to which the computers are connected. Any two computers with routable IP addresses can talk to each other. And there are other ways to make it work if you don't have routable IP addresses: see, http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip/